# A problem on epsilon and delta in the proof of L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm following the proof of L'Hospital's Rule from a text but have trouble understanding this part regarding epsilon-delta.

> Assume $L\gt 0$ and $\epsilon \gt 0$ is given and $\delta \in (0,1)$. What we have is
>
> $$(L-\epsilon)(1-\delta)-\delta\lt \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)}\lt(L+\epsilon)+\delta$$
>
> If we take $\delta=\operatorname{min}{\{1,\epsilon,\epsilon/(|L|+1)\}}$ then
> $$L-2\epsilon\le \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)}\le L+2\epsilon$$

I can't get the first inequality above. Also, shouldn't we get a strict inequality on the right side? I've tried some manipulations but all have been unsuccessful in getting that. How can I show this part?